# Code to count Prime numbers between a range returns half of the numbers

Tags: c, while-loop, counting

Some piece of this code is wrong and I can't figure it out. I write the code logically to count Prime Numbers between two given numbers but the code returns half of the range of given numbers. The functions works fine but the logic of while loop is wrong

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checkPrime(int isItPrime);

int main()
{

    printf("Counting Prime Numbers between twos\nEnter two numbers , the First number must be smaller\n");
    int num1, num2;
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    int count = 0;
    while(num1<num2)
    {
        num1++;
        if(checkPrime(num1)==1)
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}

int checkPrime(int isItPrime)
{

    int result = 0, j = 2;
    while(result < isItPrime)
    {
        result = (isItPrime%j);
        j++;
        if (result==0)
            return 0;
        else if (result!=0)
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Change it to `while(j < isItPrime)`, and delete the `else if (result!=0)` and shift the `return 1;` outside of the loop.

Comment: @Brendan It Worked , Thanks A Lot Sir , Bless You .....

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to `return 0` the very first time you get `result == 0`, but don't `return 1` the very first time you get `result != 0`. That will cause every odd number to be classified as prime. You have to check the `result` for *every* value of `j` up to the square-root of `isItPrime`. Also: as Brendan pointed out, your `while` conditional should be testing `j`, not `result`.  You could say `while(j*j <= isItPrime)`

Also also: note that your current `main()` logic tests numbers *excluding* `num1` but *including* `num2`—verify that that is in fact what you intended.

More generally:  be skeptical of your code. Don't just look at the number of (alleged) primes it reports. In initial (debugging) versions of the program, you should be actually printing out each number as it's tested, along with the test result (i.e. whether it thinks each number is prime). If you had done that, you would probably have caught the problems above, or at least narrowed it down.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works,I hope it does:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int checkPrime(int n);

int main()
{

    printf("Counting Prime Numbers between twos\nEnter two numbers , the First number must be smaller\n");
    int num1, num2;
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
    int count = 0;
    while(num1<num2)
    {
        num1++;
        if(checkPrime(num1)==1)
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
int checkPrime(int n)
{

    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's `checkPrime()` incorrectly always return in its first iteration.  It need to test more values when `result != 0`.

```
int checkPrime(int isItPrime) {
    int result = 0, j = 2;
    while(result < isItPrime) {
        result = (isItPrime%j);
        j++;
        if (result==0) return 0;
        // else if (result!=0) return 1;   // problem
    }
    return 1;  // add
}
```

---

Fixed OP's algorithm is very slow as it iterates up to `isItPrime` when iteration only up to `sqrt(isItPrime)` is needed.  Also the return value incorrect with values < 2.

```
int checkPrime_fix1(int isItPrime) {
    int result = 0, j = 2;
    // Avoid sqrt(isItPrime). Floating point has too many subtle problem for an integer task
    // Avoid j*j <= isItPrime to prevent overflow with large isItPrime
    while(j <= isItPrime/j) {
        result = isItPrime%j;
        j++;
        if (result==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return isItPrime > 1;
}
```